# What is the sense of the word "host" in 'HOSTCC' and ./configure --host?

Tags: cross-compiling, autotools, configure

Suppose I have the source for some program, the source uses GNU autotools, and to keep it simple, let's say the program is in no way a development tool of any kind. If I have a cross-toolchain handy, I can `configure` to cross-compile for the platform `fooproc-barvendor-bazos` using the `--host` option:

```
./configure --host=fooproc-barvendor-bazos
```

However, in the quiet(er) style of output adopted by various source builds including Linux 2.6,

```
HOSTCC foo.c
```

means that foo.c is being built with a native compiler for system I'm building on, to differentiate from

```
CC bar.c
```

which means that bar.c is being build with the cross compiler for the system I'm building the program for.

Did I get confused somewhere there, or does the 'host' in `HOSTCC` just not mean host in the sense of `./configure --host`?

Comment: Looking around a bit more, it seems that BUILD_CC / CC_FOR_BUILD is a common alternative to HOSTCC for specifying the native compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/)/[automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/) do not really have a notion of host compiler. `$CC` is always the target compiler. If you ever see `$HOSTCC`, it is a manual addition by the developer of the package you are looking at.

`--host` specifies on what host type the produced program is intended to be run on.

Comment: By "target compiler" do you mean the cross compiler for the platform specified to the configure script by --host, and by "host compiler" do you mean the native compiler?

Comment: Yep. HOSTCC/NATIVECC, if it existed, would be influenced by ./configure **--build=xyz** instead (not --host).

Answer (score 3):

In autoconf the terminology is:

- **build** is the system on which you are compiling.
- **host** is the system on which what you are building will run.
- **target** is what the compiler you are building will compile for, and is irrelevant when not building a compiler.

In other tools, for example ptxdist, the terminology is however:

- **host** is the system you are building on.
- **target** is the system on which what you are building will run.

So depending on what tool you have, **host** means different things.