# autoconf (configure) get host compiler when cross compiling (HOSTCC / CC_FOR_BUILD)

Tags: cross-compiling, autoconf, automake, toolchain

How should I get host compiler (e.g. `gcc`, but it could be different) when I cross compile:

```
./configure --host aarch64-suse-linux CROSS_COMPILE="aarch64-suse-linux-"
```

I get variables in `config.log`:

```
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_cpu='x86_64'
```

But I have no way to get something like `$HOSTCC` from it.
I know that when I omit `--build` [the default is `--build=$(config.guess)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Specifying-Target-Triplets.html). But regardless specifying it or use the default it does not help me to find the compiler.

Also it looks like there is no support in autotools:

- https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2011-04/msg00017.html
- [What is the sense of the word "host" in 'HOSTCC' and ./configure --host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738086/what-is-the-sense-of-the-word-host-in-hostcc-and-configure-host)

FYI I need it to add some compile-time helper tools in [LTP](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/), which uses [automake and autoconf](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/blob/master/configure.ac), [but otherwise have somehow custom build system](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/wiki/Build-System), which does not use `Makefile.am`. Thus something like [`CC=$(CC_FOR_BUILD)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201260/autotools-cross-compilation-and-generated-sources) is not available :(.

Maybe there is no way to detect it from `$build` variable (using some script) and I have to ask users to define it:

```
HOSTCC=${HOSTCC-cc}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get "build" and "target" C compiler with autoconf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674571/how-to-get-build-and-target-c-compiler-with-autoconf)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using [`AC_ARG_VAR`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html):

`configure.ac`:

```
AC_ARG_VAR(HOSTCC, [The C compiler on the host])
test -z "$HOSTCC" && HOSTCC='$(CC)'
```

`Makefile.in`:

```
HOSTCC  = @HOSTCC@
```

Credits: Gforth project: [`configure.ac`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gforth.git/tree/configure.ac#n221) [`Makefile.in`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gforth.git/tree/unix/Makefile.in#n45).

Instead of `test -z "$HOSTCC" && HOSTCC='$(CC)'` in `configure.ac` I'll add into `Makefile.in`:

```
build := @build@
host := @host@
ifeq ($(strip $(HOSTCC)),)
# native build, respect CC
ifeq ($(build),$(host))
HOSTCC := $(CC)
else
# cross compilation
HOSTCC := cc
endif
endif
```

But it'd be great if `HOSTCC` or `CC_FOR_BUILD` was supported out of the box.

Comment: BTW Although we support for `--host` parameter, I'm going to use `AC_ARG_VAR` macro also for `CROSS_COMPILE` variable in [LTP configure.ac script](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/blob/master/configure.ac).

Comment: It is supported almost-out-of-the-box with autoconf-archive, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674571/how-to-get-build-and-target-c-compiler-with-autoconf